# Rejected Digest Challenge error in SVN Client

Tags: svn

My Laptop is `Macbook Pro` and I have Mac OS X version `10.7.3`.

I am trying to connect to a repository using `Versions SVN Client`. I am unable to connect to the server and I get the following error.

> authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Digest challenge

What does this error mean and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: If a fault from a server is off topic, I think it's time to shop for a new domain name. =)

Comment: Seriously they seriously flagged question? Ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be checking out from a server which requires authentication. Are you supplying the credentials correctly ?